# drop columns in a txt file by length

Tags: python

I have a txt file with 2 columns and many rows with integers and strings (without IDs), where I need to remove rows longer that 50 characters, for example \

```
4:33333333:3333333: -:aaaaaeeeeeeeffffffffhhhhhhhh
```

I guess pandas drop function is not suitable in this case (from description: Remove rows or columns by specifying label names and corresponding axis, or by specifying directly index or column names)
Does Python have any other options?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will rewrite the file according to that rule. In this case the new paragraph character `\n` is not counted.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    rows = [line for line in file.readlines() if len(line.strip()) <= 50]
with open('out.txt', 'w') as file:
    for row in rows:
        file.write(row)
```

if you need to use the rows for something else do:

```
rows = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines() if len(line.strip()) <= 50]
```

to clean the strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could process a large text file by processing chunks (specifying the number of rows in a chunk) using pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_rows_per_process = 10 ** 6 # 1,000,000 rows in a chunk
    allowed_column_length = 50
    columns = ["feat1", "feat2"]
    input_path = "input.txt"
    output_path = "results.txt"
    with open(output_path, "a") as fout:
        for chunk_df in pd.read_csv(input_path, chunksize=n_rows_per_process, sep=r"\s+", names=columns):
            tmp_df = chunk_df[chunk_df["feat2"].str.len() < allowed_column_length]
            tmp_df.to_csv(fout, mode="a", header=False, sep="\t")
```

You will get the expected result in the `results.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You may read your file line by line and write to (other) file *only lines which fulfill your condition:*

```
MAXLEN = 50

with open("input.txt") as inp, open("output.txt", "w") as outp:
    for line in inp:
        if len(line) <= MAXLEN + 1:
            outp.write(line)
```

Every read `line` includes the (invisible) ending `\n` symbol, too, so we compare its length with `MAXLEN + 1`.